# How to use mipmap with TextureAtlas and AssetManager

Tags: java, libgdx

I searched on the Internet but couldn't find the way to use mipmaps with libGDX `TextureAtlas`. I want atlas instead of normal textures because as far as I know mipmap supports only 2^n width and height and my single textures have other width and height but atlas have 2048x1024.

I can use mipmaps with `Texture` using

```
TextureParameter param = new TextureParameter();
param.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
param.genMipMaps = true;
manager.load("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class, param);
```

but it's not working with `TextureAtlas`, I tried to change `TextureParameter` to `TextureAtlasParameter` but this class don't have `genMipMaps` field and can't be passed to `load` method, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you've a pack file along with the image, like text or json file, there probably is a line that specifies the filter used in that atlas. For example the file may be like this:

```
pack3.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
image1
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 2
  size: 484, 484
  orig: 484, 484
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
image2
  rotate: false
  xy: 488, 2
  size: 484, 484
  orig: 484, 484
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Just change the filter in there to the one you like (in the order `min,mag`) and save the text/json file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the setting `genMipMap` for TextureAtlas is not available. If you're packing your images using [TexturePacker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/texturepacker/TexturePacker.java) to create your atlas, you can pass it [Settings](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#settings):

```
TexturePacker.Settings settings = new TexturePacker.Settings();

settings.combineSubdirectories = true;

settings.filterMin = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapNearestLinear;
settings.filterMag = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;

// Packs all textures inside your "textures" folder into a folder named "pack"
// "pack.atlas" and "pack.png" will be created.
TexturePacker.process(settings, "textures", "packs", "pack");
```

Comment: So maybe do you know any other way to avoid textures distortion while moving? More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311915/scaled-textures-distorted-while-moving

Comment: @bpawel10 Try setting `filterMin` to `Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapNearestLinear` and `filterMag` to `Texture.TextureFilter.Linear`. I edited my answer to reflect this.